# Arrayformula into INDEX&MATCH for googleform responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So basically, I just want to summarize or collapse into 1 column these 5 columns (`B:F`).
My formula is in column `G:G` but it's not resulting as to my expectation (column `H:H`).

[image: GoogleSheetFormula]

I want the array effect so that I don't need to drag the formula down every time a user submits a a response in google form.

Can this be applied to a script instead of a formula?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing this formula in `G1`:

```
={
  "Class (summarize to 1 column)";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      A2:A = "",,
        TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F),, 10^7)))
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: What is 10^7 for?

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski some people use 9^9, I like 10^7 as there is a limit of 10 000 000 cells in a virtual (not present in table, only existing in memory during calculation) range. So 10^7 or 9^9 is a way of telling `QUERY` to squash together all the rows. Could be replaced with `COLUMNS(B2:F)` in this case.